# Solve a system of 2 nonlinear equations with unknows inside integral expressions

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system

I am trying to solve the following system of nonlinear equations

$$ N(x,y) = (b-x) \cdot y - \int_0^x f(\zeta(\bar{x},y)) \, d\bar{x} = A $$

$$ M(x,y) = C \cdot (b - x) \cdot y - \left( D - \frac{\int_0^x f(\zeta(\bar{x},y)) \cdot \bar{x} \, d\bar{x} }{\int_0^x f(\zeta(\bar{x},y)) \, d\bar{x} } \right) \cdot \int_0^x f(\zeta(\bar{x},y)) \, d\bar{x} = B $$

$$f(\zeta(x,y)) = \frac{k \cdot \zeta - \zeta^2}{1+ (k-2) \zeta} $$

$$\zeta = -y \cdot x$$

It looks a tad intimidating, but the idea is the following:

- A, B, C, D, k and b are known constant values
- $\zeta$ is a function of $y$ and $x$
- The first and the last integrals represent an area under a certain curve
- The fraction of two integrals is the centroid of that area

My two unknowns are $x$ and $y$ and I would like to solve this system numerically using Python. However, since I cannot express this system of equations in terms of one variable (due to $f(\zeta)$ depending on $x$ and $y$), I do not know where I should start or which solution method to use.

Edit: this is not a question about implementation in Python or coding! I would like to know how I should go about numerically solving this system.

Edit2: so, I have managed to simplify the system. Now it looks like this

$$F \cdot (b-x) \cdot y+ G = \int_0^x \frac{k \cdot \zeta(\bar{x},y) - \zeta(\bar{x},y)^2}{1+ (k-2) \zeta(\bar{x},y)} d\bar{x}, \quad \zeta(x,y) = -x\cdot y$$

$F$ and $G$ are constants; $x$ and $y$ are unknowns.

Comment: `\int` instead of `int` displays an integral symbol.

Comment: when I use \int, it tells me that I am missing a bracket. Edit: Ok, I tried it again after posting, and it worked. Perhaps it was a bug

Comment: Good job, good luck with your post.

Comment: I am not sure if it was intentional but most of your integrals are trivial to evaluate, assuming $\bar{x}$ is meant to be an independent integration variable, for example in the first equation, the integral simply evaluates to $x\cdot f(\zeta(x, y))$

Comment: I am sorry, this was a mistake. The bars should be above all x under the integrals. The point is that x is unknown, but it is at the same time the variable I am integrating and the upper limit of the integral.